# Hyphen breaks the line into multi line

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

In a a custom list view, I have a textview showing name and emailId. When the name provided is something like A-TestThisString(testA@test.com), the length of displayed area exceeds,
In that case the string is broken at the place of hyphen like

A-

is shown in the list. This is causing lots of problems. I have found one link which talks about solution bellow

topic: "Android: How do i make nonbreakable block in TextView?"

but, I am not able to understand how to use it. Please suggest.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106144/android-how-do-i-make-nonbreakable-block-in-textview?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: The above is the link which I have mentioned in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I found the answer. use the inputType as email or singleLine=True, it starts working fine.

Comment: Good Answer Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used `android:inputType="date"`, no line breaks and hyphen is displayed nicely

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="2-3 4-5"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:textSize="25sp" />
```