# Android TextView Line Break keep words together (and be efficient)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a gallery that displays a picture and a subtitle (TextView).

Now the text is broken into multiple lines if the text is long enough (correct, up to three lines) but our marketing department insists that I do not break words separated by a hyphen 
(e.g. "This is a double-word line" can be broken anywhere but on "double-word"). Problem is that Android tends to put the breaks exactly there :-)

Is there a way to set line break modes? Or any other idea that prevents those sentences from being broken into multiple lines?

One further thing: I use a coverflow effect and it really needs to be very smooth (which it is) for our marketing people to be happy. Which means that I need an efficient solution, as the text is set every time a new picture is selected (and users love to swish through them)...

Thanks and sunny greetings from Berne,
Stephan Wiesner

Comment: Your marketing people can join stackoverflow its free .

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106144/android-how-do-i-make-nonbreakable-block-in-textview)?

Comment: Sorry, that did not help. The solution does not break text at all (and the first letter of the text is omitted)

Answer (score -1):

You can use text in HTML format like

`textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=#ffff00>" + My name + "</font>" +" " +"<font color=#ffffff>" + is  +  "</br> bull. "+ "</font>"));`

Font color will change the color of text and  will move text in next line.

Don't forgot to make textview multiline in your XML.
Hope this help you .

Comment: That does not answer my question at all. I one text to be dynamically broken into multiple lines - depending on the screen size of course, just not on the hyphens.